# Batch file won't run when RUNAS is introduced

Tags: batch-file

i have a batch will with a small script as below. Now i want to modify it with **RUNAS** so that I can provide it a user without having the need to give him administrator password.

```
@ECHO OFF  
PowerShell.exe -NoProfile -Command "& {Start-Process PowerShell.exe -ArgumentList '-NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File ""%~xyz0.ps1""' -Verb RunAs}"  
PAUSE
```

I added the RUNAS with a few parameters, as shown below, but it encounters an error:

```
ECHO OFF 
runas /profile /user:Administrator /savecred "PowerShell.exe -NoProfile -Command "& {Start-Process PowerShell.exe -ArgumentList '-NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File ""%~xyz0.ps1""' -Verb RunAs}"" 
PAUSE
```

ERROR:

> Attempting to start PowerShell.exe -NoProfile -Command  as user
>   "ABC\Administrator" ... '{Start-Process' is not recognized as an
>   internal or external command, operable program or batch file. Press
>   any key to continue . . .

**PS: without introducing RUNAS, the batch file runs just fine.**

can anyone help, please.